# Reachability - Best practice before showing webView

Tags: iphone

I would like to check "reachability" before/when a webView is shown in my app.

So far I've included the reachbility.h/.m files as well as added the SystemConfiguration.framework to the project.

And that's about where the agreements I have found on the internet end, from all of the posts and blogs etc. etc. everyone has a different idea/opinion of what to do after that.  Additionally, I have found a lot partial code snippets that aren't really a complete solution, on which reachibility methods to call etc. etc. how to use them etc.

I have also found that some warn that you should try to reconnect before checking reachability...but I haven't found a consensus or a full solution.  My app seems to reconnect to wifi without any extra code... so I'm a litte confused here too...

Any help to clear the muddy waters would be appreciated.  I'm just looking for a simple straightforward solution.

Answer Accepted:  I would like to note to newbies who may read this q/a later... that you will want to do the following:

Add this into your .h file:

```
- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork: (NSString *) remoteServer;
- (void) appLoadError: (NSString *) altertTitle alertMessage: (NSString *) altertMsg;
```

And you will need to import these at the top of your .m file:

> sys/socket.h
>
> netinet/in.h
>
> netinet6/in6.h
>
> arpa/inet.h
>
> ifaddrs.h
>
> netdb.h
>
> SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h

Correct me if it is wrong... It seems to work fine for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always used this method in my App Delegate when I need to require Internet access. I have tuned it for different access types over time and it has served me well.  It is a variant of one of the many methods you can find after a quick Google search on this topic.

It is a tricky thing to come up with a hard and fast strategy around this.  The platform itself offers different connectivity options that have pros and cons based on the needs of each specific application.  The method I use below is just a general connectivity test meaning the device can reach the Internet via some connectivity mechanism.

```
- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork: (NSString *) remoteServer {
    // Create zero addy
    struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
    bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
    zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
    zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // Recover reachability flags
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&zeroAddress);
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

    BOOL didRetrieveFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags);
    CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability);

    if (!didRetrieveFlags){
        NSLog(@"Error. Could not recover network reachability flags");
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable;
    BOOL needsConnection = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired;
    BOOL nonWiFi = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection;

    NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString: remoteServer];
    NSURLRequest *testRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:testURL  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0];
    NSURLConnection *testConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:testRequest delegate:self];

    return ((isReachable && !needsConnection) || nonWiFi) ? (testConnection ? YES : NO) : NO;
}
```

I usually call this inside applicationDidFinishLaunching.  If the check returns false, I usually generate an error message (see below).  This is because Apple forbids exiting the application by any means other than the home button on the device.

```
...
else if(![self connectedToNetwork: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@:%@/", sharedSettings.server, sharedSettings.port]]){
        [self appLoadError: @"No Internet Detected" alertMessage:@"This application requires an active Internet connection.  No content is available."];        
}
...
- (void) appLoadError: (NSString *) altertTitle alertMessage: (NSString *) altertMsg {
    UIAlertView *loadErr = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: altertTitle message: altertMsg delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [loadErr show];
    [loadErr release];

    // Load static screen
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Error_NoInternet.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    [controller setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated: NO];

    [window addSubview: imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
```

Comment: sharedSettings and controller are flagging errors.  Do you have any idea what may be missing?

Comment: Shared settings is an instance on the class to hold common settings, and Controller is your app's main View Controller, you may need to change the variable name to suit your app.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note, I believe that method is leaking an `NSURLConnection` on every call (at the bottom, `testConnection`).

You might want to use

```
+ (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:
        (NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate
```

instead.